# Which type of pump is appropraite for my well?

Tags: pump, well-pump

My well is 250ft deep with a 6 inch bore. Water yield is moderate and starts from 115ft. My house is a three story building. What kind of pump would be appropriate for this application? I am confused between compressor type, jet type and submersible type pumps.

Comment: dym 6 inch bore?

Comment: 6 inch bore.  Sorry 6 mm was a typo

Answer (score 1):

At 115 feet static and 250 bottom your (sensible) options are submersible, submersible, or submersible.

Which is really "new-fangled 2-wire submersible" (my choice, matter of opinion) or "old-fangled 3 wire submersible" (avoid like plague, matter of opinion) or fancy-schmancy constant-pressure inverter-drive submersible (too expensive for me.)

Since you have a 6" bore, a 4" pump will fit nicely. Park it at 235-240 feet down the hole.